# Drag & drop and get file path in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'd like to be able to drag a file/executable/shortcut into a Windows Forms application and have the application determine the original path of the dropped file then return it as a string.

E.g. drag an image from the desktop into the application and messagebox up the local path of the image.

Is that possible? Could someone provide me with an example maybe?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's quite easy. Just enable drap-and-drop by setting the [`AllowDrop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.allowdrop) property to `True` and handle the [`DragEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter) and [`DragDrop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop) events.

In the `DragEnter` event handler, you can check if the data is of the type you want using the [`DataFormats`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataformats.aspx) class.

In the `DragDrop` event handler, use the [`Data`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.data) property of the [`DragEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drageventargs) to receive the actual data and the [`GetData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataobject.getdata) method

---

**Example:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.AllowDrop = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    For Each path In files
        MsgBox(path)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A bit cleaner: Dim files() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

Comment: With "Option Strict On", Visual Studio disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'String()' , so you have to do what Schnickelfritz suggested, and convert it to a string: Dim files() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

Answer (score 6):

This is just a note to state that if drag and drop does not work, it could be because you are running Visual Studio in Administrator Mode (Windows 7 and up I believe).

This also has to do with the [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) level currently set on your Windows installation.

Comment: Really good consideration (however it should be added as a comment under the valid answer)