# VB.NET How to drag a file from windows explorer to specific form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, drag-and-drop

In my project, user has to define few paths. By clicking a button, a window opens where you can drag and drop file/folder from windows explorer to this window. Then my application will take that path and store it.

I have a main form where is button to settings page. This opens new form by form.show. In this new form, I have another button. By clicking it, another small form will open where you can drop things (form.show). This is where things get tricky. I can't get drag and drop working.

```
Public Class drag

    Private Sub dragdrop_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.AllowDrop = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub drag_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
        Dim theFiles() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData("FileDrop", True), String())
        For Each theFile As String In theFiles
            MsgBox(theFile)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub drag_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I create new project and paste exact code to form1, it works. Why it doesn't work on this multiform project and how I can fix it?

Comment: Check this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686631/vb-net-drag-drop-and-get-file-path

Hope helpful.

Comment: Actually, what i feel is your question is exact duplicate of that.

Comment: No it's not. I have exact same code but it does NOT work on my project. If I create new project, it works. Only difference is that I have multiple forms in my project.

Comment: I know. Thats why i didnt down voted, let it be, Is that link helped you?

Comment: I can get it to work with plain new project. The code works there. But if I try to make same thing happen in my application, it doesn't work. I bet it has to do something with multiform applications (?) but I can't figure what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It's securitything with running applications as administrator priviledges in Vista/7/8.

> The problem is tied to how security permissions work. The ability to
>   drag and drop from a normal applications to an elevated one would
>   break the security model behind UAC. However, I'm unclear as to why a
>   UAC prompt isn't shown, thus allowing for a temporary elevated
>   operation (much like any linux user experiences every day). This is
>   definitely something that Microsoft needs to work on. What troubles me
>   is that this problem is already old. Vista behaved the same.
>
> There's 2 things you can do (one ugly, one annoying)
>
> Ugly: Disable UAC. But you lose all the extra security it offers.
>
> Annoying: Use another File manager and run it too as an Administrator
>   Why another file manager? Because you can't actually elevate Windows
>   Explorer. Despite seeing the option in the context menu of the Windows
>   Explorer icon and a UAC prompt being displayed, the fact is Windows
>   Explorer will not be elevated.

Comment: Source: http://superuser.com/questions/59051/drag-and-drop-file-into-application-under-run-as-administrator

Comment: Well, you could launch that part of the program which normal priviliges and only request administrator priviliges when they are needed.