# .NET 2015 winforms: drag a treenode to desktop?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, treeview

Plenty of stuff on the web about dragging between treenodes and other controls, but I have a treeview that contains lists of documents, and I can't drag anywhere outside of my main form.

I'm already allowing it to drop between nodes, and onto a ListView control. However, if I drag the node off my window, the cursor changes to the "nuh-uh!" image.

The ListView allows me to drop SelectedItems onto the desktop or Windows Explorer. The TreeView doesn't.

I noticed that ListViewItems have the property "FileLocation". I'm wondering if Windows isn't picking that up to know how to handle a drop onto Explorer?

So, I need to be able to preserve the ability to drag between nodes, between TreeView and ListView, AND onto the desktop or File Explorer.

This is the current code I'm using to do the dragdrop with the TreeView. Thanks for any suggestions:

```
    Private Sub tvAllDocuments_ItemDrag(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemDragEventArgs) Handles tvAllDocuments.ItemDrag
        If tvAllDocuments.SelectedNodes.Count > 0 Then

            For Each mySelectedNode As TreeNode In tvAllDocuments.SelectedNodes
                If mySelectedNode IsNot Nothing AndAlso mySelectedNode.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso mySelectedNode.Text.Substring(0, 1) <> "*" Then
                    tvAllDocuments.DoDragDrop(mySelectedNode, DragDropEffects.Move)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686631/vb-net-drag-drop-and-get-file-path   Notice they are using the filedrop type. You need to do the same and pass the files in the correct format. Then Windows will also work with your files.

Comment: Thanks - it was somewhat helpful. By putting the code in the MouseDown event, I can set up a dataobject which the desktop and File Explorer recognize. However, it no longer works with controls on my form.